# ionic read a local json file with $cordovaFile

Tags: android, json, path, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I'm trying to load a local json file stored like this:

www/json/config.json

```
var path = '/android_asset/www/json'; //<-i have tried lots of differnt path's without success
var fileName = "config.json";
console.log('url: '+path+fileName);
console.log('file there?: '+angular.toJson($cordovaFile.checkFile(path, fileName)) );

$cordovaFile.readAsText(path, fileName).then(function (success) {
  console.log('read success: '+angular.toJson(success));
}, function (error) {
  console.log('read error: '+angular.toJson(error));
});
```

I use ionic with the ngCordova plugin $cordovaFile... Does anyone have an advice?
I just want to ship my app with a "default" json loaded...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't read the file in your `www` folder using `$cordovaFile` with that path, `$cordovaFile` get access to the file through `file://` protocol.

Because the default json file is located in the `www` folder. Here is some ways to do that:

1. Copy all the JSON content and put it inside a javascript file, and get access to that file as a global variable. (must include this file to the `index.html`)

   ```
   var json = {myKey: "myValue"};
   ```
2. Using `$resource` as a service (not tested):

   ```
   $resource('file:///android_asset/www/json/myJson.json', {}, {
       query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
   })
   ```
3. Using `$http` within your controller:

   ```
   $http.get('json/myJson.json')
   .success(function (data) {
       // The json data will now be in scope.
       $scope.myJsonData = data;
   });
   ```